# Can't figure out the code to disable button when EditText is empty

Tags: android

**[SOLVED] The code that solved my problem:**

```
    editTextEasyResult.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(s.toString().trim()))
                answerButtonEasy.setEnabled(false);
            else
                answerButtonEasy.setEnabled(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

.

**Problem:**
I'm working on a basic math game where the player has to solve simple equations by filling in the empty field like this: `3 x 7 = __`. If the space is empty I want the correct button to be disabled. The major reason for this is because each time a player tries to solve the equation by pressing [CORRECT]-button and no numbers are written it stopps working/crashes. So I thought by forcing the player to add a number for the [CORRECT]-button to be clickable I can prevent that. I've tried a few things but so far this is the closest a working method I got (check code below), mainly because it's simple and fits the rest of my coding. However, it's not working propery - disables itself randomly.

Any tip?

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.answerButtonEasy:
                if (editTextEasyResult.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                    answerButtonEasy.setEnabled(false);
                }else{
                    answerButtonEasy.setEnabled(true);
                    int easyNum1 = Integer.parseInt(textEasyNumber1.getText().toString());
                    int easyNum2 = Integer.parseInt(textEasyNumber2.getText().toString());
                    int easyResult = Integer.parseInt(editTextEasyResult.getText().toString());
                    if (easyNum1 * easyNum2 == easyResult) {
                        for (int i = 1; i <= currentLevel; i++) {
                            currentScore = currentScore + i;
                        }//for-loop ends here
                        currentLevel++;
                        //Updates the Score and Level
                        textEasyScore.setText("Score: " + currentScore);
                        textEasyLevel.setText("Level: " + currentLevel);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Good job!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        editTextEasyResult.setText("");
                    } else {
                        currentScore = 0;
                        currentLevel = 0;
                        //Updates the Score and Level
                        textEasyScore.setText("Score: " + currentScore);
                        textEasyLevel.setText("Level: " + currentLevel);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong! :(", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                break;
        }//switch ends here
```

Comment: use editTextEasyResult.getText().toString().trim().length()

Comment: What does "randomly" mean? Even if no interaction takes place the button is disabled spontaneously?

Comment: Sorry for the bad usage of words. By random I mean it behave different from time to time. Sometimes the button is unclickable without trying to solve any equations. Other times  if I start solving equations and then by intension leave it unfilled and try to check if it works, it will. But then if I try and type something it will stay unclickable and I have to go out from that activty and enter again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be Disabling Button if `EditText` is Empty, you can do this by adding `TextWatcher` to your `EditText`:

```
            editTextEasyResult.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(s.toString().trim()))
                        answerButtonEasy.setEnabled(false);
                    else
                        answerButtonEasy.setEnabled(true);
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: I assume this goes in the `onCreate` method?

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks for doing all the coding to me mate!

Comment: urw. Well to be fair you were on the right track but using wrong tools. ^^

Answer (score 1):

```java
 try{
 if (editTextEasyResult.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                            answerButtonEasy.setEnabled(false);
                              answerButtonEasy.setClickable(false);
                        }
  } catch(Exception e)
{
    //Print error to logs//
}
```

---

or

---

```
 try{
 if (editTextEasyResult.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                            answerButtonEasy.setEnabled(false);
                              answerButtonEasy.setClickable(false);
                        }
  } catch(Exception e)
{
    //Print error to logs//
}
```

vote if it's useful..

Comment: Where do you suggest I should insert the `try {` method?

Answer (score 0):

```
    EditText mEditText;
    final Button mButton;

    mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            mButton.setEnabled(!TextUtils.isEmpty(s.toString().trim()));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add textChangedListener to your EditText.

```
myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    if(s.toString().isEmpty()){
        myButton.setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        myButton.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I generally use either:

```
if(editTextEasyResult.getText().length() == 0)
```

or

```
if(editTextEasyResult.getText().toString().equals(""))
```

or

Your can put it in a try and catch. For example

```
try
{
    editTextEasyResult.getText().toString()
{
catch(Exception e)
{
    //Print error to logs//
}
```

This will prevent your application from crashing if it tries to asign a null value

Comment: Where do you suggest I should insert the `try {` method? What regards the `if` statement, I already have tried both already, but they give sort of the same result. However, not a properly, 100%, working still.

Comment: I went with the code at the bottom. Problem Solved.